# Login to html webpage with unity

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine

So I work with unity and I was making a program that pulls data from a webpage. The only problem that I have now, is that I have to login to the webpage. I have a username and password there .I tried everything but it doesn't work. Could someone help me pls?

Here is the website:
https://dia.smartschool.be/login
Here is my script:

```
public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{

    public InputField username;
    public InputField password;

    string LoginURL = "https://dia.smartschool.be/login";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void taskready()
    {
        Debug.Log("pressed");
        StartCoroutine(LoginToSS(username.text, password.text));
    }
    IEnumerator LoginToSS(string ss_username, string ss_password)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("login_form[_username]", ss_username);
        form.AddField("login_form[_password]", ss_password);
        form.AddField("login_form[_token]", "Click");


        WWW www = new WWW(LoginURL, form);

        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);
        Debug.Log(ss_username);
        Debug.Log(ss_password);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the page in question its pretty clear why this wouldn't work - you are passing "[Click]" string as the token, where as you should be using a token that the website presents to you when it displays the form - when trying in different browsers the token is different so chances are the website wants to keep track of 'who tries to login' as a basic security feature.
I am not quite sure what the BEST way to obtain the token is, but the most obvious one is get the form first with WWW, and search the string manually. I imagine it would accept the loin once you supply it with a valid, just obtained token

Comment: Hi zambari, thanks for your answer! Do you now what the token of the website could be? Does it change every time? Maybe this is a token: -n-vGulegKBuFcVW0ab0V5Ar07yeryHTHmpmMOE2G3A   ?

Comment: yes this is how the token looks like. the website provides the token to be able to identify who is filling the form. its present in the form when the form is presented to the user as a hidden field. I imagine its only valid for a certain time

Comment: ok, so how can I obtain the token first and then fill in the username and password and then use the token for the Login button?Could you explain me with a script or something?

Comment: that's the tricky party, probably by doing a normal WWW request and parsing it (as suggested in my answer)

Comment: also, if you found my answer helpful, would you consider accepting it?